# Redirect to Mobile Site with Full Site Link

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, mobile

I'm working on setting up a redirect to a mobile landing page for mobile users and the script I'm using is throwing up a 505.

Entire htaccess code is below: (Updated)

```
<FilesMatch "\.(html|htm|js|css)$">
FileETag None
<IfModule mod_headers.c>
Header unset ETag
Header set Cache-Control "max-age=0, no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate"
Header set Pragma "no-cache"
Header set Expires "Wed, 11 Jan 1984 05:00:00 GMT"
</IfModule>
</FilesMatch>

#MobileSetup
RewriteEngine On 
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (^|&)m=0(&|$)
RewriteRule ^ – [CO=mredir:0:http://www.maindomain.com]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^http://www.maindomain.com/mobile/\.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.(jpg|css|png|gif)$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "android|blackberry|iphone|ipod|iemobile|opera         mobile|palmos|webos|googlebot-mobile" [NC]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !(^|&)m=0(&|$) [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_COOKIE}  !mredir=0 [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://www.maindomain.com/mobile/? [R,L]

#Was at the top

RewriteEngine On 
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^news/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)$ /news.php?url=$1 [NC,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^maindomain.com$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.maindomain.com$1 [R=301,L]

ErrorDocument 404 /404.php

#Redirects
Redirect 301 main site redirects

#10.28.13
Redirect 301 main site redirects
```

I've tried debugging this but to no avail. There is a redirect set up on the server that is forcing a **non-www.** to go to the **www.**.
Could this be causing an issue?

Thanks for help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you try:

```
RewriteEngine On 

RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (^|&)m=0(&|$)
RewriteRule ^ – [CO=mredir:0:http://www.regularsite.com]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^mobile-site\.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.(jpg|css|png|gif)$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "android|blackberry|iphone|ipod|iemobile|opera mobile|palmos|webos|googlebot-mobile" [NC]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !(^|&)m=0(&|$) [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_COOKIE}  !mredir=0 [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://mobile-site.com/? [R,L]
```

#### UPDATE:: Your full .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On 
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (^|&)m=0(&|$)
RewriteRule ^ – [CO=mredir:0:http://www.maindomain.com]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.(jpg|css|png|gif)$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "android|blackberry|iphone|ipod|iemobile|opera mobile|palmos|webos|googlebot-mobile" [NC]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !(^|&)m=0(&|$) [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_COOKIE} !mredir=0 [NC]
RewriteRule !^mobile/ /mobile/? [R,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^maindomain.com$
RewriteRule ^ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]

RewriteRule ^news/([\w-]+)$ /news.php?url=$1 [NC,L,QSA]
```

Comment: Hi there, that also throws up the same Internal Server Error.

Comment: Okay, the updated code is not throwing up the Internal Server Error any more. But now I am testing in Safari, and I am getting the following error: 'Safari cannot open the page because too many redirects occurred.'

Comment: Tried edited code. Still receiving 'too many redirects error' from Safari.

Comment: Try to test from a different browser.

Comment: Tried testing in Chrome for iPhone and receive the same error.

Comment: Q1. Is this the only .htaccess or do you have another? Q2. Is this the only code in this .htaccess? If you have some other code then please post it in question? Q3. What is location of above .htaccess?

Comment: @lsbweb: Edit your question and provide the code not my answer.

Comment: Done - sorry, my fault.

Comment: ok saw the edit. Your .htaccess has few problems> let me edit my answer.

Comment: Hi there - this code works, thanks! However, when someone clicks on the link to view our full website, they are taken back to the mobile page again. Should this link be just domain.com or domain.com/?m=0 ?

Comment: As per your rule once your mobile cookie is set they will be taken to mobile page. If you come from a different desktop browser then it won't be directed to mobile OR else `http://domain.com/?m=0` will be opening main site.

Comment: I understand, thanks. But what about a mobile user, who ends up at domain.com/mobile/ and clicks the link to visit the main website. They get taken back to the mobile site again.

Comment: Well for them the link to main site should be: `http://domain.com/?m=0` and then it will be opening the main site.

Comment: If it helped you then please consider marking it as "accepted", so users facing a similar problem in the future will be able to see it easily.

Comment: Okay thank you - thanks for all your help with this. :) Unfortunately, the application on the mobile page has stopped working. When I remove the |iphone| from the RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} line, and go to the URL from my iphone, the application works.

Comment: Well I haven't just copy/pasted your own mobile agents so that part you need to take care of. Everything else is doing fine I believe and for that you should mark this answer as accepted.